# What are Volterra classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I want to learn about Volterra classifiers in-depth to understand the following papers
Papers

1. https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Kang_Convolutional_Neural_Networks_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf
2. [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51855543_Trainable_Convolution_Filters_and_Their_Application_to_Face_Recognition#:~:text=Each%20Volterra%20classifier%20is,has%20a%20three%2Dtiered%20architecture](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51855543_Trainable_Convolution_Filters_and_Their_Application_to_Face_Recognition#:%7E:text=Each%20Volterra%20classifier%20is,has%20a%20three%2Dtiered%20architecture).
   I planning to do a mini project and want to understand these papers.
   Need introductory materials for better understanding

Comment: As was hinted [when you asked on AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/25503/1794), we expect you to [research the topic on your own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723) before asking, summarize what you've found and provide background to make the question useful for others, and use that to craft a more narrowly focused question.  See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  It looks like you've found the paper that introduced the idea of Volterra classifiers, so I'm not sure what other introductory materials you're expecting.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!